# setExtent causes ScrollView not found error in BlackBerry 9000

Tags: blackberry, scrollview, runtime-error

This--

```
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.VerticalFieldManager;

public class FixedHeightVerticalFieldManager extends VerticalFieldManager 
{
  private int height;

  public FixedHeightVerticalFieldManager(int height)
  {
    super();
    this.height = height;
  }

  protected void sublayout(int maxWidth, int maxHeight)
  {
    super.sublayout(maxWidth, height);
    setExtent(height);
  }
}
```

--causes the emulator to hang with the runtime exception `net.rim.device.api.ui.ScrollView not found`.  It seems to be caused by the call to `setExtent`, which is a method `VerticalFieldManager` inherited from `Field`, which is in the 4.6 API that the emulator is set up to use.  Why?  What does ScrollView have to do with anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`net.rim.device.api.ui.ScrollView` is not available in 4.6 API - that's the reason. So I suspect you're using the `ScrollView` somewhere in your code while you are trying to run on a 4.6 OS simulator.

Also what API version is used to build the project? Normally (if you'd use 4.6 API lib/JDE) you should have got this error at building step (versus in runtime).

**UPDATE**:

I really have no idea why this is related to `setExtent()`.

I suspect most likely you compile using API 6. For API 6 the inheritance chain looks as `Field` > `ScrollView` > `Manager` > `VerticalFieldManager`, so when you compile a `VerticalFieldManager` it may use `ScrollView`. Maybe that's why you get the error on API 4.6 simulator. You can test this idea by trying to run your app on any OS 6.0 simulator. I believe it should not give this error.

P.S. I have not used BB Eclipse plugin much (once I tried, but then refused because of some issues), so I can't say where exactly to check the API version. However surely there must be a way to check that.

Comment: The word ScollView doesn't appear anywhere in my project.  The project compiles and runs if I leave out the setExtent call.  The setExtent call is somehow requiring ScrollViews presence, which makes no sense to me.  I'm compiling in Eclipse, not BlackBerry JDE; it seems to be using JRE 6.0.0?

Comment: @Ben Williams: please check the UPDATE section.

Comment: Good call; the problem goes away in the 6 sim.

Comment: @Ben Williams: then solution is obvious either use OS 6 simulator with the current development environment OR change the development environment to use 4.6 API lib in order to run on 4.6 simulator.

Comment: And having finally -- finally! -- convinced Eclipse to actually install and use 4.6, it works on the phone too.  Thanks!